# How to get 3 images by regex from a page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to get 3 images by regex from a page:
I have a code:

```
<?php
$post_id = 29;
$post_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_content->post_content;
$regex = '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i';
$output = preg_match_all($regex, $content, $images);
$content = preg_replace($regex, '', $content);

?>
<div class='gallery_item'>
  <div class="readmore"><a href="/airports">See more projects</a></div>

  <?php

  foreach ( $images[0] as $image ) {
    echo '<div class="item_thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-4"><a href="/airports">' . $image . '</a></div>';
  }
  ?>
  <div class="project-title"><h4>Airports</h4></div>

</div>
```

I don't know how to add a condition to get 3 images from a page
Can you show me ?
I'm a newbie :(
Thanks !

Comment: You want to display only 3 images ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to display 3 images ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to display 3 pictures :

```
<?php 
$post_id = 29;
$post_content = get_post($post_id); 
$content = $post_content->post_content;
$regex = '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i';
$output = preg_match_all($regex, $content, $images);
$content = preg_replace($regex, '', $content);

?>
<div class='gallery_item'>
    <div class="readmore"><a href="/airports">See more projects</a></div>
    <?php
    $nb_to_display = 3;
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < $nb_to_display; $idx++) {
        echo '<div class="item_thumbnail col-sm-3 col-md-4"><a href="/airports">' . $images[0][$idx] . '</a></div>'; 
    }
    ?>
    <div class="project-title"><h4>Airports</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working :(
It's just display "Array"
https://imgur.com/iUrdZeE.png

Comment: Can you describe how is your array ? (maybe with var_dump($images))

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your mind ? All my code is in question #1, but I tried your code but it's not working -> https://i.imgur.com/iUrdZeE.png
Sorry, I'm newbie :(

Comment: It's awesome ! Thank you very much :)